# 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I am programming in python 3.8 using tensorflow==2.2 and I'm not very sure about solving this problem. Does anyone have any idea?

The code is:

```
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn as tfl
import random
import json
import pickle
```

and the error is:

```
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\initializers\__init__.py", line 85, in populate_deserializable_objects
    generic_utils.populate_dict_with_module_objects(
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'
```

when I trie:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.1
```

to solve the problem it says me there is not any version compatible.

Thanks you very much

Comment: Try downgrading to 2.1 [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic\_utils' has no attribute 'populate\_dict\_with\_module\_objects'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137954/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-python-keras-utils-generic-utils-has-no-attr)

Comment: Yes, I have already seen people who do this and solve the problem, but when I trie "pip install tensorflow==2.1" I get this error:    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.1 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.1

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can be resolved if you can downgrade `tensorflow` to `2.1`

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow==2.1 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3,
> 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.1

But, you got above error because you are using `Python 3.8`. According to tensorflow documentation, it should be between `3.5 to 3.7`. Once you downgrade python version accordingly your issue will be resolved.