# why is this attribute error showing up and what is the solution to it

Tags: attributes, attributeerror

i m running a code and its giving this attribute error pls help

[the error that is shows while running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8f5y.png)

the code i am using:_

```
import cv2
from deepface import DeepFace

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if not cap.isOpened():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    result = DeepFace.analyze(frame, actions = ["emotion"])

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.1,4)

    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

    cv2.putText('video',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic\_utils' has no attribute 'populate\_dict\_with\_module\_objects'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137954/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-python-keras-utils-generic-utils-has-no-attr)