# I am not able to importing keras efficientnet B0 even I installed keras-efficientnets

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

```
from keras_efficientnets import EfficientNetB0

AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'
```

I installed keras-efficientnets, I installed tenserflow, but it is showing error while importing.

Comment: your version of keras or keras_efficientnets does not support the version of TensorFlow that you have installed

Comment: Please refer to that solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137954/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-python-keras-utils-generic-utils-has-no-attr

Comment: Above issue is due to incompatibility between Tensorflow as Keras. Instead of above you can try a workaround `from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB0` will resolve your issue.Thanks!