# AttributeError: could not import keras and segmentation models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, attributeerror, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to import segmentation models and keras and i am getting an attribute error, i am using tensor flow version 2.5.0

```
import tensorflow as tf
import segmentation_models as sm
import glob
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import keras 

from keras.utils import normalize
from keras.metrics import MeanIoU
```

Attribute error :

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'
```

I tried installing tensorflow 2.1.0 version to solve the issue as recommended in other question, but still the problem persists, any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

As suggested in comments , i am updating output of pip list

pip list :

```
pip list
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- -------------------
absl-py                            0.12.0
alabaster                          0.7.12
anaconda-client                    1.8.0
anaconda-navigator                 2.0.3
anaconda-project                   0.10.0
antlr4-python3-runtime             4.8
anyio                              2.2.0
appdirs                            1.4.4
argh                               0.26.2
argon2-cffi                        20.1.0
arrow                              0.13.1
asn1crypto                         1.4.0
astroid                            2.6.0
astropy                            4.2.1
astunparse                         1.6.3
async-generator                    1.10
atomicwrites                       1.4.0
attrs                              21.2.0
autopep8                           1.5.6
Babel                              2.9.1
backcall                           0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache      1.6.4
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0
backports.tempfile                 1.0
backports.weakref                  1.0.post1
beautifulsoup4                     4.9.3
binaryornot                        0.4.4
bitarray                           2.1.0
bkcharts                           0.2
black                              21.4b2
bleach                             3.3.0
bokeh                              2.3.2
boto                               2.49.0
Bottleneck                         1.3.2
brotlipy                           0.7.0
cachetools                         4.2.2
certifi                            2021.5.30
cffi                               1.14.5
chardet                            4.0.0
click                              8.0.1
cloudpickle                        1.6.0
clyent                             1.2.2
colorama                           0.4.4
conda                              4.10.1
conda-build                        3.21.4
conda-content-trust                0+unknown
conda-pack                         0.6.0
conda-package-handling             1.7.3
conda-repo-cli                     1.0.4
conda-token                        0.3.0
conda-verify                       3.4.2
contextlib2                        0.6.0.post1
cookiecutter                       1.7.2
cryptography                       3.4.7
cycler                             0.10.0
Cython                             0.29.23
cytoolz                            0.11.0
dask                               2021.6.2
decorator                          4.4.2
defusedxml                         0.7.1
detectron2                         0.4.1
diff-match-patch                   20200713
distributed                        2021.6.2
docutils                           0.17.1
efficientnet                       1.0.0
entrypoints                        0.3
et-xmlfile                         1.1.0
fast-slic                          0.4.0
fastcache                          1.1.0
filelock                           3.0.12
flake8                             3.9.0
Flask                              1.1.2
flatbuffers                        1.12
fsspec                             2021.6.0
future                             0.18.2
fvcore                             0.1.5.post20210609
gast                               0.4.0
gco-wrapper                        3.0.7
gevent                             21.1.2
glob2                              0.7
gmpy2                              2.0.8
google-auth                        1.31.0
google-auth-oauthlib               0.4.4
google-pasta                       0.2.0
greenlet                           1.1.0
grpcio                             1.34.1
h5py                               3.1.0
HeapDict                           1.0.1
html5lib                           1.1
hydra-core                         1.1.0
idna                               2.10
image-classifiers                  1.0.0
imageio                            2.9.0
imagesize                          1.2.0
importlib-metadata                 3.10.0
importlib-resources                5.1.4
ImSegm                             0.1.8
inflection                         0.5.1
iniconfig                          1.1.1
intervaltree                       3.1.0
iopath                             0.1.8
ipykernel                          5.3.4
ipython                            7.22.0
ipython-genutils                   0.2.0
ipywidgets                         7.6.3
isort                              5.9.1
itsdangerous                       2.0.1
jdcal                              1.4.1
jedi                               0.17.2
jeepney                            0.6.0
Jinja2                             2.11.3
jinja2-time                        0.2.0
joblib                             1.0.1
json5                              0.9.6
jsonschema                         3.2.0
jupyter                            1.0.0
jupyter-client                     6.1.12
jupyter-console                    6.4.0
jupyter-core                       4.7.1
jupyter-packaging                  0.7.12
jupyter-server                     1.4.1
jupyterlab                         3.0.14
jupyterlab-pygments                0.1.2
jupyterlab-server                  2.4.0
jupyterlab-widgets                 1.0.0
Keras                              2.3.1
Keras-Applications                 1.0.8
keras-nightly                      2.5.0.dev2021032900
Keras-Preprocessing                1.1.2
keyring                            23.0.1
kiwisolver                         1.3.1
lazy-object-proxy                  1.6.0
libarchive-c                       2.9
llvmlite                           0.36.0
locket                             0.2.1
lxml                               4.6.3
Markdown                           3.3.4
MarkupSafe                         1.1.1
matplotlib                         3.4.2
mccabe                             0.6.1
mistune                            0.8.4
mkl-fft                            1.3.0
mkl-random                         1.2.1
mkl-service                        2.3.0
mock                               4.0.3
more-itertools                     8.8.0
mpmath                             1.2.1
msgpack                            1.0.2
multipledispatch                   0.6.0
mypy-extensions                    0.4.3
navigator-updater                  0.2.1
nbclassic                          0.2.6
nbclient                           0.5.3
nbconvert                          6.1.0
nbformat                           5.1.3
nest-asyncio                       1.5.1
networkx                           2.5.1
nibabel                            3.2.1
nltk                               3.6.2
nose                               1.3.7
notebook                           6.4.0
np-utils                           0.5.12.1
numba                              0.53.1
numexpr                            2.7.3
numpy                              1.19.5
numpydoc                           1.1.0
oauthlib                           3.1.1
olefile                            0.46
omegaconf                          2.1.0
opencv-python                      4.4.0.46
openpyxl                           3.0.7
opt-einsum                         3.3.0
packaging                          20.9
pandas                             1.1.4
pandocfilters                      1.4.3
parso                              0.7.0
partd                              1.2.0
patchify                           0.2.3
path                               16.0.0
pathlib2                           2.3.5
pathspec                           0.8.1
pathtools                          0.1.2
patsy                              0.5.1
pbr                                5.6.0
pep8                               1.7.1
pexpect                            4.8.0
pickleshare                        0.7.5
Pillow                             8.2.0
pip                                21.1.2
pkginfo                            1.7.0
planar                             0.4
pluggy                             0.13.1
ply                                3.11
portalocker                        2.3.0
poyo                               0.5.0
prometheus-client                  0.11.0
prompt-toolkit                     3.0.17
protobuf                           3.17.3
psutil                             5.8.0
ptyprocess                         0.7.0
py                                 1.10.0
pyasn1                             0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                     0.2.8
pycocotools                        2.0.2
pycodestyle                        2.6.0
pycosat                            0.6.3
pycparser                          2.20
pycurl                             7.43.0.6
pydocstyle                         6.1.1
pydot                              1.4.2
pyerfa                             2.0.0
pyflakes                           2.2.0
Pygments                           2.9.0
pylint                             2.8.3
pyls-black                         0.4.6
pyls-spyder                        0.3.2
pyodbc                             4.0.0-unsupported
pyOpenSSL                          20.0.1
pyparsing                          2.4.7
pyrsistent                         0.17.3
PySocks                            1.7.1
pytest                             6.2.4
python-dateutil                    2.8.1
python-jsonrpc-server              0.4.0
python-language-server             0.36.2
python-slugify                     5.0.2
pytz                               2021.1
PyWavelets                         1.1.1
pyxdg                              0.27
PyYAML                             5.4.1
pyzmq                              20.0.0
QDarkStyle                         3.0.2
qstylizer                          0.1.10
QtAwesome                          1.0.2
qtconsole                          5.1.0
QtPy                               1.9.0
regex                              2021.4.4
requests                           2.25.1
requests-oauthlib                  1.3.0
rope                               0.19.0
rsa                                4.7.2
Rtree                              0.9.7
ruamel-yaml-conda                  0.15.100
scikit-image                       0.18.1
scikit-learn                       0.24.2
scipy                              1.5.4
seaborn                            0.11.1
SecretStorage                      3.3.1
segmentation-models                1.0.1
Send2Trash                         1.5.0
setuptools                         57.0.0
simplegeneric                      0.8.1
singledispatch                     0.0.0
sip                                4.19.13
six                                1.15.0
sniffio                            1.2.0
snowballstemmer                    2.1.0
sortedcollections                  2.1.0
sortedcontainers                   2.4.0
soupsieve                          2.2.1
Sphinx                             4.0.2
sphinxcontrib-applehelp            1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp              1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp             2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath               1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp               1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml      1.1.5
sphinxcontrib-websupport           1.2.4
spyder                             5.0.3
spyder-kernels                     2.0.3
SQLAlchemy                         1.4.19
statsmodels                        0.12.2
sympy                              1.8
tables                             3.6.1
tabulate                           0.8.9
tblib                              1.7.0
tensorboard                        2.5.0
tensorboard-data-server            0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit             1.8.0
tensorflow                         2.5.0
tensorflow-estimator               2.5.0
tensorflow-gpu                     2.5.0
termcolor                          1.1.0
terminado                          0.9.4
testpath                           0.5.0
testresources                      2.0.1
text-unidecode                     1.3
textdistance                       4.2.1
threadpoolctl                      2.1.0
three-merge                        0.1.1
tifffile                           2021.6.6
tinycss                            0.4
toml                               0.10.2
toolz                              0.11.1
torch                              1.6.0+cu101
torchvision                        0.7.0+cu101
tornado                            6.1
tqdm                               4.51.0
traitlets                          5.0.5
typed-ast                          1.4.2
typing-extensions                  3.7.4.3
ujson                              4.0.2
unicodecsv                         0.14.1
Unidecode                          1.2.0
urllib3                            1.26.5
watchdog                           1.0.2
wcwidth                            0.2.5
webencodings                       0.5.1
Werkzeug                           2.0.1
wheel                              0.36.2
whichcraft                         0.6.1
widgetsnbextension                 3.5.1
wrapt                              1.12.1
wurlitzer                          2.1.0
xlrd                               2.0.1
XlsxWriter                         1.3.8
xlwt                               1.3.0
xmltodict                          0.12.0
yacs                               0.1.8
yapf                               0.31.0
zict                               2.0.0
zipp                               3.4.1
zope.event                         4.5.0
zope.interface                     5.3.0
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Comment: Can you show the segment of the code where this error is raised?

Comment: @StrangeSorcerer : import segmentation_models as sm is the segment of code where i find the error

Comment: Could you provide the output of "pip list"? And the output of tf.__version__

Comment: Have you tried opening another script and trying to use the attribute directly? something like `from keras.utils.generic_utils import populate_dict_with_module_objects`. To see if the problem is in segmentation_models or keras

Comment: @StrangeSorcerer , yes i did and this is the output  ImportError: cannot import name 'populate_dict_with_module_objects' from 'keras.utils.generic_utils' (/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py)

Comment: @Sr.S , i have updated the question , the version of tensorflow is 2.5.0 print(tf.__version__)
2.5.0

Comment: Have you visited this link yet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137954/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-python-keras-utils-generic-utils-has-no-attr
Some of the solutions involve downgrading python as well as tensorflow

Comment: When you're receiving this error? From the link recommended by StrangeSorcerer, you can try **import tensorflow.python.keras.utils**

Comment: @Sr.S  this is the error that i am receiving  when i tried to import as you have said raise ImportError(msg.format(parent_name),
ImportError: parent 'keras.utils' not in sys.modules

Comment: @StrangeSorcerer , Yes i have visited the link before, sadly no hope. I tried all the approaches mentioned in that link

Comment: Lets continue in the chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234415/question-68209795

Comment: set this: `sm.set_framework('tf.keras')`

Comment: @Kaveh , no its not working at all

Comment: And then change all imports from `from keras import --` to `from tensorflow.keras import --`

Comment: @ i think that i not useful at all, i tried these approaches

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved my issue by adding `tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()` to import and it works fine

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras 
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
import segmentation_models as sm
import glob
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
#import keras 
from tensorflow.keras.utils import normalize
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import MeanIoU
```

Comment: Same error: AttributeError: module 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'generic_utils'

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the cause but I added `time.sleep(3)` after setting environmental variable and it worked.