# How do I fix this error I get when I import keras into python?

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to import keras into python and keep getting this error. I have checked all of the installs and can not figure out what is going on

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mpdom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import initializers
  File "C:\Users\mpdom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    populate_deserializable_objects()
  File "C:\Users\mpdom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\__init__.py", line 82, in populate_deserializable_objects
    generic_utils.populate_dict_with_module_objects(
AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic\_utils' has no attribute 'populate\_dict\_with\_module\_objects'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137954/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-python-keras-utils-generic-utils-has-no-attr)

Comment: you may also want to refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14632) . if you are in tensor flow 2.0, keras need to be replaced with tf.keras