# Keras errors only when using poetry

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-poetry

I have an ML project using the following dependencies:

```
Keras==2.4.3
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
Python=^3.9
tensorflow==2.5.0
```

So far so good, works on my machine, etc. If I add those dependencies to pyproject.toml and use `poetry run ./project.py`, however, I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./project.py", line 1, in <module>
        import keras
      File "~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-i7Jy80Zo-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
        from . import initializers
      File "~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-i7Jy80Zo-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/initializers/__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
        populate_deserializable_objects()
      File "~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-i7Jy80Zo-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/initializers/__init__.py", line 82, in populate_deserializable_objects
        generic_utils.populate_dict_with_module_objects(
    AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'
```

Which seems to be related to [question 61137954](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137954/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-python-keras-utils-generic-utils-has-no-attr), which itself relates to tensorflow apparently installing its own keras.

That's great, but a) most of the workarounds I've tried break Keras features I'm actually using, b) it doesn't answer the question: why is my poetry build different from my local env?

Comment: Replace `import keras` in the first line of  `project.py`  with `from tensorflow import keras`

Answer (score 0):

Code works with

```
Tensorflow = 2.6
keras-preprocessing~= 1.1.2
keras~= 2.6
python = 3.7
```

As commented by @Kaveh, replace `import keras` with `from tensorflow import keras`