# repeated error : AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'

Tags: python, tensorflow

This error keeps popping up when I try to import tensorflow as tf  ..
It's stuck from From old code in which I used this :
tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils

I think it's stored somewhere and is repeated to me from memory but I don't have experience with Python so I can't find an explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic\_utils' has no attribute 'populate\_dict\_with\_module\_objects'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137954/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-python-keras-utils-generic-utils-has-no-attr)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the `tf-nightly` packages and then try like below,

```
pip uninstall tf-nightly
pip install tensorflow --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

Comment: Well I didn't have tf-nightly but i upgrade tensorflow to 2.11 and the error goes away :)

Comment: but now the problem is module 'tensorflow 2.11' has no attribute 'lite' , tensorflow 2.2.1 had lite

Comment: The same issue come to me in tensorflow 2.11 and the error remained related to Tensorflow, when I go back to the old one, the error that stuck with it appears, and when I install the new one, its error appears . what I did is that I uninstall python and deleted its file and install it again, this freed me from the stuck error